# Append values to javascript dictionary

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create the following data structure in javascript:

```
d = {"foo": [3, 77, 100], "bar": [10], "baz": [99], "biff": [10]}
```

My starting data structure is a a list of dictionaries:

```
input = [{"key": "foo", "val": 3}, {"key": "bar", "val": 10}, {"key": "foo", "val": 100}, {"key": "baz", "val": 99}, {"key": "biff", "val": 10}, {"key": "foo", "val": 77]
```

How can I generate my desired data structure? The following code doesn't seem to append values to the value array.

```
var d = {}

for (var i in input) {
    var datum = input[i];
    d[datum.key] = datum.val
}
```

Comment: What's `hops`?  Don't you mean `var datum = input[i];`?  P.S. Don't use `for..in` for arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/a/500531

Comment: Iterate the `input`, see if `d` has a property for each value of `"key"`, and if not, give `d` a property using that value, and assign an array. Then push the value of `"val"` into the Array.

Comment: Ah, thanks. My fault, typo.

Comment: A JavaScript "dictionary" is called an object. Just FYI.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var datum = input[i];
    if (!d[datum.key]) {
        d[datum.key] = [];
    }
    d[datum.key].push(datum.val);
}
```

FYI, you shouldn't use `for (var i in input)` to iterate over an array.

Comment: You were a tad bit faster than me. Same exact answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative:

```js
const input = [{ "key": "foo", "val": 3 }, { "key": "bar", "val": 10 }, { "key": "foo", "val": 100 }, { "key": "baz", "val": 99 }, { "key": "biff", "val": 10 }, { "key": "foo", "val": 77 }]
const dict = {}

input.forEach(({ key, val }) =>
    key in dict ? dict[key].push(val) : dict[key] = [val] )

console.log(dict);
```

And a one-liner, with immutability

```
input.reduce((dict, { key, val }) => ({ ...dict, [key]: [...dict[key] || [], val] }), {})
```

Comment: What a neat solution. Thanks for the help

Comment: It is unreadable. Please do not use arrow operators in maintainable code. Thank you.

Comment: Not all javascript/typescript programmers adopt as their primary language, some imperative one. Someone can look at an imperative code and consider it bloated and having unnecessary mutations. Where did you get this about not using the arrow operator in maintainable code? I can see lots of them in lodash, react and axios source code. In fp-ts, I can only see arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, with `reduce`.

```
var d = input.reduce(function (res, item) {
    var key = item.key;

    if (!res[key]) res[key] = [item.val];
    else res[key].push(item.val);

    return res;

}, {});
```

Comment: Probably not the clearest for newbie but I like it :)

Comment: @user1523882, Yeah it might not be, but I really like to make use of the `initialValue` of the reduce functions to build maps like this. Once you get used to it it's nice because you can do it in a single *external* statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = {}
input.forEach(function(keyObject){
  //Make array for key if doesn't exist
  result[keyObject.key] = result[keyObject.key] ? result[keyObject.key] : [];
  //Add value to array
  result[keyObject.key].push(keyObject.val);
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be do the next:

```
for (var i in input){
    var datuml = input[i];    
    if(!d[datuml.key]){
        d[datuml.key]=[];
    }
    d[datuml.key].push(datuml.val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have more then 1 key?
Well, I think you want something like convert JSON to ArrayString.

Check this [Convert JSON To Array Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601494/convert-json-to-array-javascript)
and this [How to convert JSON object to JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528385/how-to-convert-json-object-to-javascript-array)

etc

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
        var input = [{ "key": "foo", "val": 3 }, { "key": "bar", "val": 10 }, { "key": "foo", "val": 100 }, { "key": "baz", "val": 99 }, { "key": "biff", "val": 10 }, { "key": "foo", "val": 77 }];
        var d = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            var entry = input[i];
            if (d[entry.key] === undefined) d[entry.key] = [];
            d[entry.key].push(entry.val);
        }

        alert(JSON.stringify(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

**PRO-TIP:**

You can define it as a expression so you can reuse it multiple times and keep your code readable.

***Examples:***

```js
const pushToDict = (dictionary:any, key:any, value:any) => {
    (dictionary[key] = dictionary[key] || []).push(value);
};
```

*typescript version*

```js
const pushToDict = (dictionary, key, value) => {
    (dictionary[key] = dictionary[key] || []).push(value);
};
```

*javascript version*

And you call it like this...

***Example of usage:***

```js
pushToDict(dict, key, value);
```